# Dynamic Helper Column?

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, dynamic-arrays, excel-365

I wish to create a helper cell using a dynamic array, Is this possible?

Normally I use a formula such as in this example `=IF(A4="",C2,A4)` which check if column A is blank and if so just copies the above value until a new value appears in column A.

However as shown in the image when I insert New rows the helper cell becomes broken.

For this reason I wanted to use a dynamic array to create the helper cell which should be able to handle rows inserted or removed.

The problem I have is that unlike a normal formula which you can just drag down, a dynamic array is looking at the values as a whole. Using `=IF(A4:A40="","-",A4:A40)` inserts a hyphen as shown in the image. Essentially I wish to replace the hyphen such that "For each value between A4:A40 check if blank and if true take the value in the above cell".  In essence creating a dynamic helper column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inexact form of Match to find the last row which is not blank, and then Index to take the value in column A from there:

```
=INDEX(A4:A40,MATCH(ROW(A4:A40),IF(A4:A40<>"",ROW(A4:A40))))
```

This sort of thing is done a lot in Google Sheets.

[image]

If you insert a row, the formula changes to

```
=INDEX(A4:A41,MATCH(ROW(A4:A41),IF(A4:A41<>"",ROW(A4:A41))))
```

and still works OK.